# CentOs 5.3, Yum Update Fails

Tags: yum, upgrade

```
sh-3.2# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* epel: www.muug.mb.ca
* base: mirror.its.sfu.ca
* updates: mirror.its.sfu.ca
* webtatic-el5: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
* extras: mirror.its.sfu.ca
* addons: mirror.netflash.net
epel   | 3.6 kB     00:00
8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2    | 1.2 kB     00:00
http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/x86_64/repodata/8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure:
repodata/8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2 from c5-testing: 
[Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

CentOS release 5.3 (Final)

I can't find what is broken.

I've tried 'yum clean all' and adding new repositories.

Answer (score 3):

Please open:

```
/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf
```

...and change 1 to 0 on the "enabled" option.

Then:

```
yum clean all
```

Also, instead of permanently disabling the fastestmirror plugin, you can add the broken mirror to the exclude line in:

```
/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf
```

That's all you can do when you get errors from mirrors that are severely out of date.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. Here's the output now: <br /> `sh-3.2# yum update
8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2                          | 1.2 kB     00:00     
http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/x86_64/repodata/8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2 from c5-testing: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.`

Comment: Having trouble figuring out Stack Exchange's formating.  `sh-3.2# yum update    
8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2                          | 1.2 kB     00:00       
http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/x86_64/repodata/8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum  
Trying other mirror.  
Error: failure:   repodata/8596812757300b1d87f2682aff7d323fdeb5dd8ee28c11009e5980cb5cd4be14-primary.sqlite.bz2 from c5-testing: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.`

Comment: Try with `yum clean all --enablerepo="*"; yum update` If that doesn't help you can skip the repo with the broken mirror via `yum update --disablerepo="CentOS-Testing*"` which is the one that causes the issue in your example. You can also check if the affected repo uses `failovermethod=priority` - in case it does, edit it and switch it to `roundrobin` as **priority** would cause it to fail and stop with the first miror that isn't working, **roundrobin** will just try to use the next mirror for that repo.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out. Sort of.

I have another server where yum works fine. I looked at the repositories there and there were fewer than on the trouble server. So on the trouble server I deleted the 'extra' repositories, then did 'yum clean all'.

Now it works.

The repositories I deleted:

CentOS-Testing.repo
virtualmin-bleed.repo
webtatic-archive.repo
webtatic.repo
remi.repo
webtatic-el5.repo
webtatic-testing.repo

The repositories that remain:

CentOS-Base.repo
CentOS-Media.repo
epel.repo
epel-testing.repo
virtualmin.repo